# Unable to click login button on angular site in IE (Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-11

For some reason I seem unable to click a login button when using the selenium IEDriver. It works fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

Website is http://www.notacv.com/

Simple code...

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.notacv.com");
IWebElement element2 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.container-fluid.hero ul li:nth-child(1)"));
element2.Click();
```

I've tried the following to remedy the problem with no success

- Have tried referencing both the li and the a tags
- Both XPath and CSS selector - both confirm to find only one  element via Chrome developer toolbar
- Thread.sleep (prevents the error but does nothing when it gets to the click)
- Repeating the click and the wait
- Javascript, JQuery and angular waits
- SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
- actions -> moveto.Click()
- Explicit wait to check displayed, visibility, enabled
- Protractor for C#

Does anyone know how to fix this for IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the current link https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

Make sure you applied required changes

- The IEDriverServer exectuable must be downloaded and placed in your PATH.
- On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value
  can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set
  the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the
  Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will
  be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected
  Mode".
- Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher. This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet
  Options dialog.
- The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
- For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance
  of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations,
  the key you must examine in the registry editor is
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
  Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows
  installations, the key is
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
  Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the
  FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be
  created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
  DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.